# Remove sticky footer when scrolled to top of page

Tags: html, jquery, css

I have  sticky footer, that appears on scroll down and when the scroll position is just above the footer, it stops being sticky. I am trying to edit this code such, it stops being sticky when the page is scrolled to the top as well.

Below is the code:

```js
function checkOffset() {
  if ($('#float').offset().top + $('#float').height() >=
    $('#footer').offset().top - 10)
    $('#float').css('position', 'absolute');
  if ($(document).scrollTop() + window.innerHeight < $('#footer').offset().top)
    $('#float').css('position', 'fixed'); // restore when you scroll up

}
$(document).scroll(function() {
  checkOffset();
});
```

```css
div.float-parent {
  width: 100%;
  height: 1000px;
  background: #f8f8f8;
  position: relative;
}

div#float {
  width: 200px;
  left: 10px;
  bottom: 10px;
  background: #777;
  position: fixed;
}

div#footer {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  background: #eee;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="float-parent">
  <div id="float">
    float...
  </div>
</div>
<div id="footer">
</div>
```

Fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/2Lzsw8fj/)

Comment: Can you out the code in a jsfiddle?

Comment: @jqueryHtmlCSS added the link to the fiddle